# To change FullCalendar Cell background color on an Event in Angular 6 Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I have a requirement, i need to change the background color of some cells of the calendar which have Events on them.

The events are dynamically populated from the db, now i want to change the colors of the cells with multiple colors based on some logic i have added in the .ts file.
I have come across multiple solutions, but they are in JQuery, and i have added all this in Typescript.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: any reason you can't re-write the jQuery versions in TypeScript/JavaScript? Everything jQuery does must have a JavaScript equivalent, because jQuery is simply a layer of convenience methods on top of JavaScript.

Comment: Anyway, unless you show us some relevant bits of your code, and also specify the **exact** behaviour you want to see (because "some logic" is not an implementable requirement!), and also show us the jQuery examples you think would provide equivalent functionality, then it's really not possible for us to give you specific advice on how to implement it.